# Multiple alarms with AlarmManager in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

All the posts that are there on SO are using PendingIntent.getBroadcast(). Can we set multiple alarms with PendingIntent.getService()? I tried a code with PendingIntent.getService() for single alarm. It works fine. But I dont know how to set multiple alarms with PendingIntent.getService(). And using PendingIntent.Broadcast() s not issuing even a single alarms.

Experts plz help! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Can we set multiple alarms with PendingIntent.getService()?

Sure, so long as they are not using `_WAKEUP` alarms. The recipe for reliable `_WAKEUP` alarm requires a broadcast `PendingIntent`.

> But I dont know how to set multiple alarms with PendingIntent.getService().

The same way you set up multiple alarms with any `PendingIntent`: call `set()`, `setRepeating()`, or `setInexactRepeating()` with a *distinct* `PendingIntent`. By "distinct" I mean that it has to differ in type (activity, service, or broadcast), or the `Intent` objects must not match on `filterEquals()`, or the request code used in the `PendingIntent` factory method (e.g., second parameter to `getService()`) must differ.

Comment: I'm using getBroadcast(), different Intent and different request code for the PendingIntent and still getting only one alarm firing off. Any idea why?

Comment: @Dpedrinha: Use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` and confirm that you are actually scheduling more than one alarm. Beyond that, you would need to ask a separate question with a [mcve].